# Global variable used inside a instance method without "global"

Tags: python

I thought global variables inside a Python function had to be declared *global*. So why does the following compile and run without error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
text = "why is this seen?"
class Foo:
    def doit(self):
        print(text)
x = Foo()
x.doit()
```

I'd appreciate a citation to the Python3 manual if possible.

Comment: The global keyword is only *needed* when you are assigning to the global variable inside the function , but if you are assigning to it once, it becomes local variable (even if its used before assignment) .  If you are not assigning to that, python will treat it as the global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for a reference to the Python 3 manual. I've bolded the section that says you don't need to use the `global` keyword to reference free variables.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global_stmt

> 7.12. The global statement
>
> global_stmt ::=  "global" identifier ("," identifier)*
>
> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the
>   entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to
>   be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a
>   global variable without global, although **free variables may refer to
>   globals without being declared global**.

Note that in most code all of the classes and functions that you reference are globals (or builtins) but you didn't think twice about not needing `global print` before calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Its all about [scope](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html#execution-model), since `text` is declared outside, free from any class or function, it can be reached from anywhere. To get a better idea, consider these two examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
text = "why is this seen?"
class Foo:
    def doit(self):
        text = "this is changed"
        print(text)

x = Foo()
x.doit()
print text
```

In the above example, we overwrite the `text` variable locally, in the `Foo`, class, but the global instance of text is the same. But in this instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
text = "why is this seen?"
class Foo:
    def doit(self):
        global text
        text = "this is changed"
        print(text)

x = Foo()
x.doit()
print text
```

We declare that we want the `global` version of text and then we can modify it.

**BUT**: `global` variables are frowned upon, consider using input arguments to functions and returning new values instead of having variable globally accessible everywhere

The right way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Foo:
    text = "why is this seen?"
    def doit(self):
        print(self.text)

x = Foo()
x.doit()
```

Have `text` encapsulated in the class!

Comment: To add to this, the `global` keyword only needs to be used to __change__ the global variable outside of the current scope

Comment: @muddyfish thanks for the addition :D

Comment: @muddyfish To add to adding to this, it's considered very unpythonic to use `global`. Your first attempt should be to use `return` values, using global only when necessary.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Isn't the purpose of stackoverflow to educate people on how to do things first and then if they should do those things secondarily?

Comment: @muddyfish Certainly, that's why I'm not suggesting your answer is wrong. I'm just adding more info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a variable using `global` if you just need to access it. You can do that without a `global`.

**Here,** Python will look in the class `Foo` scope first for the `text` variable. Since, it does not find the variable `text` in the `Foo` class so it will look into outer scope. Now, it finds the variable `text`, so it uses that value to print the output.

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces),  at any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:

> 1. the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> 2. the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also
>      non-global names
> 3. the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
> 4. the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names