# Inconsistency in name resolution for local variables, class variables, and instance variables

Tags: python, variables, scoping

If I have a function like this:

```
x = 10
def foo():
    print(x)
    x = 20
    print(x)
```

Calling foo throws an `UnboundLocalError` at first `print`. So it looks like the symbol table is constructed at parse time. But this is inconsistent with name resolution for class variables.
For example:

```
x = 10
class A:
    print(x)
    x = 20
    print(x)
```

prints `10` and `20`. So the symbol table for the class is updated while its running.

The same thing goes for member variables.

```
class A:
    x = 10 
    def foo(self): 
        print(self.x)
        self.x = 20
        print(self.x)
a = A()
a.foo()
```

prints `10` and `20`. The symbol table for the instance is again updated at runtime. The first `print(self.x)` does not throw just because there's an assignment to it later.

What is the rationale behind this inconsistency? 
Why doesn't the symbol table for functions get updated at runtime instead? Is it purely for performance reasons?

Comment: Related [Python variable scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error) ... [Why the difference in handling unbound locals in functions versus classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638633/why-the-difference-in-handling-unbound-locals-in-functions-versus-classes), ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/23471004/2823755

Comment: ... [Function closure vs. callable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966785/function-closure-vs-callable-class).  Maybe a duplicate in there somewhere?

Comment: The third example has nothing to do with the other two. There you simply have a class attribute which is subsequently shadowed by an instance attribute.